# trying to connect php code to phpmyadmin using xampp & local host can't find htdocs path

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I am new in development field. I am trying to connect my php code to phpmyadmin database using xampp & it's not connecting to the local host, showing that there isn't anything inside htdocs but in fact I have added php code files at root level of htdocs already.

URL : http://localhost:8012/htdocs/
error: Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.56 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1t PHP/8.2.4 Server at localhost Port 8012

I tried to get solutions from tutorials & docs but it didn't work out.

Comment: Why do you expect that it is on port 8012, instead of the standard port? Did you configure that in Apache settings?

Comment: P.s. the problem seems to be the wrong url to access your php script, which is nothing to do with your database

Comment: htdocs is configured as the web root directory. It is not part of the GET request. Try [http://localhost/](http://localhost/) or [http://localhost:8012/](http://localhost:8012/)